# Make DataTable Scroll Bidirectional in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make DataTable Scroll Bidirectional.
I made the datatable scroll Horizontally but my list is large and unable to scroll down.

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Bills Receivable"),),
      body:SingleChildScrollView( 
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, 
        child:
           DataTable(
          columns: <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(label:Text("BNm",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
            DataColumn(label:Text("BDt",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
            DataColumn(label:Text("BPrty",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
            DataColumn(label:Text("BdueDt",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
            DataColumn(label:Text("Dys",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
            DataColumn(label:Text("BAmt",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
            DataColumn(label:Text("BPAmt",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
            DataColumn(label:Text("BBAmt",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),))
          ], rows:  widget.rdata.bRecDtl.map((e)=>
            DataRow(
              cells:<DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text(e.bNm.toString())),
                DataCell(Text(e.bDt.toString())),
                DataCell(Text(e.bPrty.toString())),
                DataCell(Text(e.bdueDt.toString())),
                DataCell(Text(e.dys.toString())), 
                DataCell(Text(e.bAmt.toString())),
                DataCell(Text(e.bPAmt.toString())),
                DataCell(Text(e.bBAmt.toString())),
          ])).toList()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 97):

Just add two `SingleChildScrollView`s:

```dart
child: SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: DataTable()
```

Comment: The scroll bar on the horizontal scrolling is not showing in futter web, how can I make it visible?

Comment: Add a Scrollbar widget to each of the SingleChildScrollView, and set their individual scrollbarOrientation property to ScrollbarOrientation.right (for vertical) and ScrollbarOrientation.top respectively on the Scrollbar widgets.

Comment: While this works, see my solution below for a more modern solution :)

Answer (score 36):

## Newer and more efficient way after Flutter update:

As of the most recent Flutter update, you can also wrap your `DataTable` in an `InteractiveViewer` widget with the `constrained` property set to `false`. Unlike earlier solutions, this will allow you to scroll both horizontally and vertically at the same time. It is also less code and lets you zoom in/out of your DataTable.

Good luck!

Comment: For some reason `InteractiveViewer` affects performace in a big DataTable as compared to `SingleChildScrollView`. Yet InteractiveViewer has more and better usability. Hopefully the situation will change after a couple of versions

Comment: @Alex.F I assume the fast zooming in and out functionality affects adds some heavy load to the rendering process. But as long as the table is small and one wants some added functionality this widget is very nice!

Comment: @ExoticSquid Can you achieve this with flutter web? cuz it didn't work with me...

Comment: @user10033434, I tested it on Flutter Web. It is working just fine.

Comment: Tested on Flutter Web. The main issue is that scrolling is bind to the scale/zoom of the `InteractiveViewer `. Event with `scaleEnable = false` in the option, you won't be able to scroll vertically on your table. You will have to pan, which is not ideal on the web.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone here is using a PaginatedDataTable or PaginatedDataTable2, you need to set the minWidth property in order to get the horizontal scroll working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two SingleChildScrollView or one InteractiveViewer.

But if you want two fixed scrollbars like this.

[Bidirectional scrolling with fixed scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onCoy.gif)

I used two SingleChildScrollView and [adaptive_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_scrollbar) v2.1.0 to get this result.

Source Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:adaptive_scrollbar/adaptive_scrollbar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Bidirectional Scrollbars',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _verticalScrollController = ScrollController();
    final _horizontalScrollController = ScrollController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 700,
        child: AdaptiveScrollbar(
          underColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.3),
          sliderDefaultColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
          sliderActiveColor: Colors.grey,
          controller: _verticalScrollController,
          child: AdaptiveScrollbar(
            controller: _horizontalScrollController,
            position: ScrollbarPosition.bottom,
            underColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.3),
            sliderDefaultColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
            sliderActiveColor: Colors.grey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _verticalScrollController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _horizontalScrollController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 16.0),
                  child: DataTable(
                    showCheckboxColumn: true,
                    columns: [
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Name'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Name'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Year'),
                      ),
                    ],
                    rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
                      20,
                      (int index) => DataRow(
                        cells: <DataCell>[
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text('Row $index'),
                          ),
                        ],
                        onSelectChanged: (bool? value) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The flutter team announced that they are developing an official solution for this problem here's the video [Preview: Two-dimensional scrolling in Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDZ0LPQq-n8), and Flutter 3.13 is out and it has added TwoDimensional scrolling foundation, more info in [What’s new in Flutter 3.13](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-13-479d9b11df4d), and it is also updating data tables to use this new 2D Scrolling, with some other improvements, the progress can be seen in GitHub  [2D Scrolling • flutter](https://github.com/orgs/flutter/projects/32).

Answer (score 2):

There is a new package maintained by the Flutter team that a 2 dimensional scrollable. It supports diagonal, vertical, and horizontal.

[2D Scrollables](https://pub.dev/packages/two_dimensional_scrollables)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: ...,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to code this way, and it works fine:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:followmeifucan/constants/style_constants.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';


class RankScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static String id = 'ranks_screen';

  @override
  _RankScreenState createState() => _RankScreenState();
}

class _RankScreenState extends State<RankScreen> {
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  List<DataCell> _createCellsForElement(DocumentSnapshot document){
    Timestamp timestamp = document.data['when'];
    return <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Text(document.data['name'].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(document.data['level'].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(document.data['round'].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(document.data['hits_ok'].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(timestamp.toDate().toString().substring(0, 16))),
      DataCell(Icon(document.data['plataform'].toString() == 'Android' ? Icons.android : FontAwesomeIcons.apple))
    ];
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'logo',
                child: Container(
                  height: 30.0,
                  child: Image.asset('images/default_icon.png'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
            Text('HIGHSOCRES'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream:  _firestore.collection('ranks').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  List<DataRow> rankLines = new List<DataRow>();
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    final ranks = snapshot.data.documents;
                   for(var rankData in ranks){

                     rankLines.add(
                         DataRow(
                             cells: _createCellsForElement(rankData)
                         )
                     );
                   }
                  }
                  return Container(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: DataTable(
                        sortAscending: true,
                        sortColumnIndex: 3,

                        columns: <DataColumn>[
                          DataColumn(label: Text('NAME', style: kRankLabelStyle,)),
                          DataColumn(label:Text('LEVEL', style: kRankLabelStyle,), numeric: true,),
                          DataColumn(label:Text('ROUND', style: kRankLabelStyle,), numeric: true,),
                          DataColumn(label:Text('HITS OK', style: kRankLabelStyle,), numeric: true,),
                          DataColumn(label:Text('WHEN', style: kRankLabelStyle,),),
                          DataColumn(label:Icon(Icons.phone_iphone)),
                        ],
                        rows: rankLines,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```